# What is this green cloud over Duran's head?

Tags: seiken-densetsu-3

I'm playing Seiken Densetsu 3 and after a battle this green cloud appeared over Duran. What is it and how do I get rid of it? Puipui Grass or Stardust Herb seem to have no effect.

[image: apologies for the resolution]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I found via a quick search on [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588648-seiken-densetsu-3/faqs/13682)

> *Poison: HP slowly decreases.  Lasts character is Healed, Dies, or  Battle Ends.  Indicated by small green bubbles above person's head.

Comment: That's correct, he is poisoned.

Comment: Green bubbles are almost always indicator for poison (would have been my comment, but then found a source ....)

Comment: Indeed, it was poison. This actually appears to be a game bug, because it was still present out of battle (status is supposed to disappear when battle ends) and I wasn't losing any HP from it. The poison status disappeared a while later when I was travelling by cannon.